# Change application switcher

Tags: release-freya, applications, window-management

Is there an easy option to change or edit the default application switcher?
The current switcher is pretty cool with this fade of the windows and the reordered Plank when I just enjoy the system, but when I work I need to remove all animations/fades and those little slowdowns.

At the moment I am with two monitors an when I press Alt+Tab the application at the current window is fading to the left/right (depending on which monitor) edge of the monitor which is the center of the two monitors together, but it is annoying for me. I prefer to disable this fade.

Also Plank animation when Alt-Tabing is small. I like bigger in the middle of the monitor switchers, something like Unity default switcher.

Comment: Indeed the other thread is about the same thing, but without any table solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak that behaviour with elementary tweaks or dconf-editor in
`/org/pantheon/desktop/gala/animations/`.

Edit #1: Well, some of them, not sure about alt+ tab fade animations.

Edit #2: This might be a solution, although, i haven't tested it yet and you need to build it from source: [Custom Gala Window Manager](http://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/2vy27d/is_there_any_way_to_disable_the_alttab_animation/)

Comment: I have already disabled animations from Elementary Tweaks, but this doesn't remove the application switcher animation.

Comment: I'm still looking through dconf-editor, I'm not sure you can do that.

Comment: It's a window manager thing, if it's making you a big problem, maybe you should consider switching to another, more lightweight window manager (like xfwm for example).

Comment: I don't want to change the window manager. It's great, just it needs a switch for power usage. I am not with weak machine, just I need it to respond faster.